# Magento 2.4.0 versus 2.3.5 regarding CentOS 6 vs CentOS 7 and the version of Elasticsearch

Tags: installation, elasticsearch, centos, magento2.4.0, magento2.3.5-p2

*We currently run our Magento stores on 1.9.4.* **It is time for us to upgrade** but our hosting company tells us we are not able to install Magento 2.4.0 due to the fact that it requires a CentOS 7 Upgrade (we currently only have CentOS 6 running) saying:

> "...versions of Elasticsearch higher than 6.X cannot run on the same
> due to the highest available version of glibc on CentOS 6. With the
> above in mind, we recommend first upgrading your server to a CentOS 7
> and then we can install Elasticsearch version 7.X on the same."

There are 2 big questions here:

1. If we upgrade to CentOS 7 - are we going to be able to run Magento 1.9.4 and 2.4.0 side by side given the different requirments?

and

2. Would we be able to install and run Magento 2.3.5 on CentOS 6? and is this preferable over Magento 2.4.0? **We are not likely to upgrade Magento for a while so maybe it would be best to start with the highest version currently available? (2.4.0)**

Comment: Hi, 
1. If you upgrade to CentOS 7 - then you will be able to run Magento 1.9.x and Magento 2.4 without having any problem. 

2. Yes, Magento 2.3.x will run on CentOS 6. Magento 2.3.x should be good to go as compare to 2.4, especially when it comes to Elastic search. This is a very good read about why M2.3.x is stable than M2.4.
https://www.yireo.com/blog/2020-09-03-unstable-release-of-magento-2-4-0

Comment: You must check if your server allows you to have multiple versions of `PHP`. Magento 1.9.x and 2.3.x runs in diff `PHP` versions. Inchoo may have a solution for you but still, that might not be the best solution, since it is only supporting `PHP 7.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Magento installation will depend on your `php` version not on your os as per my understanding wheras `magento 2.3.5` does not have support for `php 7.4` so it would be better to use `php 7.3` as of now which can run both magento2.3.5 as well as 2.4.0.

coming back to elastic search yes the default sql search has been deprecated in 2.4.0 and now the recemented one is ES7 and also the `PHP 7.1 and 7.2` deprecated so `2.4.0` cannot be installed with these.

**For more information you can go through this official release notes**

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/release-notes-2-4-0-open-source.html

**To know about magneto 1.9 since am not very familiar with it you can refer this Ans for better understanding**

https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-1-x/Magento-1-9-x-and-PHP-Version/td-p/77189